# Convert date format in SQL SERVER - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck in a weird requirement. I am just hoping that I might get some help.

My requirement is that the incoming data in table is like 
`'Thu Feb 18 11:03:18 GMT 2016'` and it's output must be
`2016-02-18` i.e. in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Any ideas!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with some other sample data,

```
DECLARE @input varchar(50)='Thu Feb 18 11:03:18 GMT 2016'
select cast(replace(substring(@input,4,len(@input)),'GMT','') as datetime)
select cast(cast(replace(substring(@input,4,len(@input)),'GMT','') as datetime) as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alongside with @KumarHarsh's answer, you can use this too:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(MAX)= 'Thu Feb 18 11:03:18 GMT 2016';
SELECT  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@input, 4, LEN(@input)), 'GMT', ''), 20),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```